# start: unrecognized service while starting MySQL on WSL Debian

Tags: mysql, wsl-2

I am trying to install MySQL8 on WSL Debian distribution.
I have installed it following [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install_mysql8_debian10/)
And when I try

```
mysql --version
```

I get correct output showing the version.
But when trying to start the service through `sudo service mysqld start`
I get the following error: `mysql: unrecognized service`.
What is the problem? And how to fix it?

Comment: @Zep No. But I tracked the problem further and I think it is due to WSL using its own init system instead of Systemd (which is so common in the Linux world nowadays). So, logically, you either have to write a script to start the service with the WSL init system (but I couldn't find further information about it) or you have to switch to Systemd. I tried the second, but it turns out it is not a straightforward process. At first, I thought it worked, but it introduced bugs handling services later. The problem is probably the collision between it and the WSL init system.

Comment: @zep It might be helpful for you to know that Ubuntu on WSL2 comes with Systemd out of the box and services like MySQL8 work seamlessly.

Comment: I am using Debian, and activated systemd but to no avail. In the end I gave up and used WSL + XAMPP with mysql 8